# Find the Terrain Width and Height in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, terrain

fellow developers :)

I wrote a script for a RTS camera that prevents the camera from going off the terrain (when the player moves the camera with WASD / arrow keys, found in another script, not included below).

As you can see, in my code below, I have hardcoded the width and height of the terrain. I want to be able to automatically detect the width and height of the terrain.

Note: I am very new to Unity and C# so if you know the answer, please provide a complete code not just fragments, ty :)

```
public class CameraBounder : MonoBehaviour {
int minXBound = 50;
int maxXBound = 50;
int minZBound = 100;
int maxZBound = 200;
int terrainWidth = 500;
int terrainHeight = 500;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Debug.Log("X: " + transform.position.x + " Z: " + transform.position.z);

    if (transform.position.x > terrainWidth - maxXBound) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 ((terrainWidth-maxXBound), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    } 
    if (transform.position.x < minXBound) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (minXBound, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
    }
    if (transform.position.z > terrainHeight - maxZBound) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, (terrainHeight-maxZBound));
    }
    if (transform.position.z < minZBound) {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, transform.position.y, minZBound);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you autogenerate the terrain via script?

Comment: @cj93 No, I create the terrain manually. But I want to be able to use the script for multiple scenes/levels without having to change the width and height in the script for each scene.

Comment: Have you tried with TerrainData.size? https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TerrainData-size.html

Comment: yeah, but I don't know how to use it. Like I said, I'm very new :( Could you provide the lines of code that get the terrain width and height from TerrainData and assign it to my custom variables terrainWidth and terrainHeight, please?

Comment: Seems that TerrainData.size.y could return the maximum height point. However, I've never used it...you could try it either, and see what value it returns.

Answer (score -1):

As you said in your comment, you generate the levels manually so, one solution will be make public Gameobjects and use their coordinates as a points.

And then take the position of this gameobjects to do your calculations.

```
public class CameraBounder : MonoBehaviour {
  public GameObject right;
  public Gameobject left;
  public Gameobject top;
  public Gameobject bottom;
  float minXBound;
  float maxXBound;
  float terrainWidth;
  int terrainHeight;

  // Use this for initialization
  void Start () {
     minXBound = left.transform.position.x; 
     maxXBound = right.transform.position.x;
     terrainWidth = maxXBound-minXBound;
     terrainHeigh = top.transform.position.y - bottom.transform.position.y;
     //You get the idea
  }
}
```

When you create the level in the inspector you will need to create the empty gameobjects at the edges and set to the public variables to your script via inspector.